# "define:" oneboxing selects completely bogus data

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

I found this weird word, "burke", and decided to check it out. It turned out it was an alternative spelling of "berk". This is what `define: berk` in chat expanded to:

[image: yeah, right]

So, according to that, "berk" as a noun can mean "a fool, prat, twit", or "berk", or "berk", or "berk". Wow, who would have thought "berk" might mean berk. Three times, just to be sure.

That got me really curious so I checked the wiktionary page directly. It shows three meanings for "berk": the same as meaning #1 that was oneboxed, plus two others that are not at all simply stated as "berk".

Further down from there we can find the other three "berks". Number three, for instance, is easy to trace since "indefinite plural berkë" seems quite greppable. And it turns out that it's Albanian.

[image: omg it has the word cunt!]

Comment: Congrats working *cunt* into a question in a context that may likely ensure it doesn't get edited out.